# iPhone making a map like in Fire Emblem

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I want to make a RPG where you engage foes utilizing a map/grid. I'm just trying to figure out how this could be done in Objective-C... also, I do not want to use OpenGL; no tilemaps. :P

Comment: With lots and lots and lots of code, basically.

Comment: @user298261, Cocos2d uses openGL and provides a tilemap interface for it.  :D  Including Spritesheets, and animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That game looks like it's using OpenGL ES. But, you could achieve somehting similar with a combination of isometric projection maps and A* pathfinding (and yes, lots and lots of code). Here's some links to research on those subjects. Beyond that, there's not really a definitive answer because there's many ways of doing this.

[Isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)

[A* Pathfinding for Beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Cocos2d.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) they have excellent tileset library tools, in addition to sprite manipulation.  Check out [Ray Wenderlich's tutorials here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d) it's really quite easy to use.

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid using a game engine. I was really looking for people to contribute ideas on code structure (i.e. using a uniquely built array, etc.).

Comment: @user, WHY?!?!?!  [THat's like the first rule of indie game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-things-should-an-indie-game-developer-never-do) - use someone else's tools and focus on what makes your game *fun.*